# Hadoop input from different servers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have one master node and two data nodes which are in different servers. For the two data node, each of them has a log file in its own HDFS. Now I want to run the Hadoop to do a map/reduce on master node and the input should be the two log files from the two data nodes' HDFS. Can I do this? If I can, how can I set the input path ? (e.g. hadoop jar wordcount.jar datanode1/input/logfile1 datanode2/input/logfile2 output ...like this?) Is it possible that the input from the different datanode's HDFS which are in different servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say **Hadoop**, there is nothing like **its own HDFS**. HDFS is a **distributed** FS and is **spread** across all the machines in a Hadoop cluster functioning as a single FS.

You just have to put both the files inside one HDFS directory and give this directory as input to you MapReduce job.

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/path/to/the/input/directory"));
```

Same holds true for MapReduce jobs. Although you submit your job to JobTracker, the job actually runs in a **distributed fashion** on all the nodes of your cluster, where data to processed is present.

Oh, one more thing...A file in HDFS is not stored as a whole on any particular machine. It gets chopped into small **blocks** of 64MB(configurable) and these blocks are stored on different machines randomly across your cluster.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you. One more thing, if I want run hadoop with my own map/reduce method, just like this: hadoop jar xxx.jar input output ...right?

Comment: You are right. Feel free to accept the answer if you feel you got your query answered so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Hi: About the Hadoop, I also have the following question:

Comment: 1: What is Hadoop Client?

Comment: 2: How does the HDFS look like? e.g. I have 2 datanodes and replication 2. When I do "hadoop dfs -put test.log input" that store a file into the HDFS, how is this file stored in the Hadoop Cluster? Is it spread over the whole cluster and stored on both two datanode servers?

Comment: 3: When I do some operation such as word count "hadoop -jar word count.jar input output", what does the whole process look like? The jobtracker will ask 2 task trackers to execute parallel and then store the output into HDFS?

Comment: Could I think that case 2 is related to the namenode/datanode and case 3 is related to the job tracker/task tracker?

Comment: 1: Anything that tries to talk to Hadoop is a Hadoop client. 2: You might find this answer helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639931/where-does-hadoop-save-a-file-to-in-a-multi-node-setup/17642405?noredirect=1#comment25721000_17642405

Comment: 3: See this : http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_book/chapter-MapReduce_Internals.html   4: Yes.